# PHP: How can I get the "Hello World!" out of this array in a $variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, meta

I have a little problem with my array and I hope someone can help me here:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Pagekit\Blog\Model\Post Object ( 
    [id] => x 
    [title] => x 
    [slug] => x
    [user_id] => x 
    [date] => DateTime Object ( 
        [date] => 2016-12-28 07:51:02.000000 
        [timezone_type] => 3 
        [timezone] => UTC 
    ) 
    [content] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [excerpt] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [status] => xxxxxxxxxxxx 
    [modified] => DateTime Object ( 
        [date] => 2016-12-28 09:17:48.000000 
        [timezone_type] => 3 
        [timezone] => UTC 
    ) 
    [comment_status] => 1 
    [comment_count] => 0 
    [user] => Pagekit\User\Model\User Object ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [username] => xxxxxxxxxxxx 
        [password] => xxxxxxxxxxxx 
        [email] => xxxxxxxxxxxx 
        [url] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
        [registered] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2016-12-15 15:33:36.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => UTC 
        ) 
        [status] => 1 
        [name] => xxxxxxxxxxxx 
        [login] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2016-12-27 13:55:45.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => UTC 
        ) 
        [activation] => [permissions:protected] => [roles] => Array ( 
            [0] => x 
            [1] => x 
        ) 
        [data] => Array ( 
            [admin] => Array ( 
                [menu] => Array ( 
                    [dashboard] => x 
                    [user] => x 
                    [system: system] => x 
                    [blog] => x
                    [system: marketplace] => x
                    [portfolio] => x
                    [site] => x
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [comments] => [roles] => Array ( ) 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [title] => [markdown] => 1 [image] => Array ( 
            [src] => storage/bilderbuch/bild.jpg 
            [alt] => bild 
        ) 
        [meta] => Array ( 
            [og:description] => Hello World! 
        ) 
    ) 
)   
)
```

Can somebody explain me how I can get the `Hello World!` or everything else from here: (the last lines in this big array)

```
[meta] => Array ( 
            [og:description] => Hello World!
```

in a `$Variable`? I know this is may a stupid question but I'm using PHP only since a week or something.

Comment: That actually is an object inside an array, not a simple array.

Comment: So this depends on the implementation of the class `Post` which we do not know. You did not tell us.

Comment: `$array[0]->data['meta']['og:description']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$variable` is an array with 1 item inside.
This item is an `Pagekit\Blog\Model\Post` Object, so first you need `$variable[0]` to get there.

Note - this object has several attributes, and you are looking for the `data` attribute: `$variable[0]->data`.

This attribute is an `array` itself, where the `meta` is one of it's keys `$variable[0]->data['meta']`, which is another array with the `og:description` key.

So the final variable you need is actually

```
$variable[0]->data['meta']['og:description']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've used https://pagekit.com/docs/developer/orm

In your case you can iterate through your results and return the metadata:

```
$meta = [];
foreach ($array as $post)
{
    $meta[] = $post->data['meta'];
}
var_dump($meta);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was :

```
$test = spliting($posts, 3);
$var1 = $test[0]->data['meta']['og:description'];
```

here the spliting function only divides the whole array in 3 parts.